# Regexp matches and captures in pry, rubular, but not from script

Tags: ruby, regex

So, I have a regexp that I have tested on Rubular and from the CLI (using the `pry` gem). This  parses a custom Apache log format. When I feed input to it in pry, it works as expected (e.g. `$~` is populated.) Rubular also reports correct matching and grouping for various lines of input. When run from the code below, no matches.

I have also tried messing with `String.chomp!` and the `\n` character, in case that was throwing off the match, but various permutations have no effect.

I'm sure it's something a more experienced Rubyist could shed some light on.

Rubular link: http://www.rubular.com/r/fycHVYZdZz

Here is the relevant code, regex, and input -- and thanks in advance:

```
log_regex = %r{
            (?<ip>(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))                                                                   
            \s-\s
            (?<src_ip>.*)
            -\s
            (?<date>\[.*\])
            \s
            (?<url>".+")
            \s
            (?<response>\d{3})
            \s
            (?<length>\d+)
            \s
            (?<referer>".+")
            \s
            (?<useragent>".*")
            \s(?<host>.*)?
            /ix
            }

logfile = ARGV[0]

def process_log(log_regex,logfile)
    IO.foreach(logfile, 'r') do |line|
        line.chomp!
        log_regex.match(line) do |m|
            puts m['ip']
        end
    end
end

process_log(log_regex,logfile)
```

Sample input:

```
209.123.123.123 - - [05/Jul/2012:11:02:01 -0700] "GET /url/mma/rss2.0.xml HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "FeedBurner/1.0 (http://www.FeedBurner.com)" xml.somewhere.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take a close look at the definition of your regex. Your flags are inside the definition of the pattern, instead of following the closing of `%r` where they belong:

```
%r{
...
/ix
}
```

should be:

```
%r{
...
}ix
```

From IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> %r{foo/ix}
/foo\/ix/
irb(main):002:0> %r{foo}ix
/foo/ix
irb(main):003:0> %r{^foo$}ix =~ 'foo'
0
irb(main):004:0> %r{^foo/ix$} =~ 'foo'
nil
```

Both PRY and IRB return the same results for the above tests.

Comment: I had subtly put the `ix` in the appropriate place in pry, but didn't in the script. With the (relative) complexity of the regexp used, and since I'm coming from another language, it went totally unnoticed. Thank you, kind sir!